# How does apt-get autoremove work when given a package as an argument?

Tags: apt, package-management

I recently logged onto a shared server to see why I couldn't access a samba share. I tried to open `smb.conf` with `vim` and found out that `vim` wasn't installed anymore. I found out that my Samba share was inaccessible because `samba` was also no longer installed.

I looked in `apt`'s logs and saw the timestamp by when Samba was removed and looked in `auth.log` and found this line right around that time:

```
COMMAND=/usr/bin/apt-get autoremove libpython3.8-stdlib
```

Every example I can find of `apt`/`apt-get autoremove` shows it invoked with no argument. What happens when you give it a package? Does this explicitly remove that package and all its cascading dependencies? This is the only explanation I can think of that would explain why `samba` and `vim` would be uninstalled.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are (almost) correct in your assumption. Running `apt-get autoremove <package>` will first remove `<package>`, and then autoremove as if you had run `apt-get autoremove` with no parameters *(i.e. removing all "automatically installed" packages that are not a dependency of any "manually installed" packages)*.

The important distinction here is that the autoremove part of running `apt-get autoremove <package>` will remove not only packages that are a dependency of `<package>`, but **all** packages that would otherwise be autoremoved.